# Close active tab-content when click on active tab - twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using twitter bootstrap and I want that active tab-content close when click on active tab.

I use this code, but this is not working:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
        $($(this).attr('href')).removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.. Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This is working but not perfectly. I edit the bootstrap.js and replace this

```
  $(document).on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
  })
```

with this one

```
      $(document).on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
      if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')){

       $( $(this).attr('href') ).removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).parent('li').removeClass('active');
       if ( $(this).parent('.dropdown-menu') ) {
              $(this).closest('li.dropdown').removeClass('active')
            }
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
        }
      })
```

but I also want that if child menu of dropdown tab is active, when I click on that dropdown tab, class "active" should remove from that dropdown tab and that's child menu tab-content.

Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Removing "active" class does it better

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active')
    $( $(this).attr('href') ).removeClass('active');
  }
  else {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  }
});
```

You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/tekbreak/NQ97h/182/

But if you need it to occurs on every tab selector, use this jQuery selector

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(...
```